# How can I generate a HTTP/rtmp output(URL) using ffmpeg/OBS and use that URL to play on a media playback device?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, obs

I tried using ffmpeg -i inputsource http://IP/live and even tried modifying win.conf file in my nginx folder by pushing rtmp://IP but when i use either http or rtmp URL in media playback device, I keep getting errors.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: There's no error but when I paste the rtmp URL on VLC(different network though) it doesn't show anything.

Comment: “I keep getting errors.” -> “There's no error”. Which is it?  Please put accurate information into the question. It’s a lot easier to help if this is not a detective game.

Answer (score 0):

This [Answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/26258/24237) might help you in using `ffmpeg` as **RTMP server**.

Comment: I tried but that doesn't work either, so basically I want to stream using ffmpeg and generate a rtmp output url which someone else can use to see the live stream.

Comment: Can you specify your question and describe your current setup in detail. What components do you have already at your disposal?